# Nginx Rails production suddenly stopped working

Tags: nginx, centos, ruby-on-rails, centos7

I am using Rails with Postgres and Redis running on Nginx on Centos7.
I have encountered interesting behavior today, my production server became offline for some time. The server refused connections and the logs suddenly started showing the following line:

```
nginx rails 52008 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client ...client_ip...
```

The application itself did not have any problems and even the remote Rails console started without any errors. Server was accessable via ssh. Restarting nginx service did not solve the problem. The only solution came from rebooting the system and restarting everything manually.
Searching for this particular error message proved to be no use, other people encountered it due to misconfiguration of nginx upon starting the server, it did not appear suddenly out of nowhere like in my case.

I am greatful to any help in figuring out what that was.

**Update**

There actually were errors in the application logs. Production log of the release in question showed:

```
PG::UnableToSend: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
```

Which points towards an error with Postgres, which I also don't understand.
Could it have been caused by me restarting the system or server, or could it be the cause of application server failing?

Comment: If you're running automatic security updates will it be possible that nginx got updated and configuration changed?

Comment: I am not sure whether my server has default automatic security updates for nginx.

Comment: But even so, I wonder why restarting nginx was not enough, I had to actually reboot the system

Comment: Your app server was not running.

Comment: Nginx was running and gave these errors. Application server showed no errors in production log, and its console could be started via capistrano script.

Comment: I was wrong, there were errors. See edit.

Comment: You can run `rails console` even if the app isn't running. So that doesn't tell you anything.